# Loading several Album Cover Photos at once?

Tags: image, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk, access-token

Currently I used the Graph API to return the albums of a Facebook Fan Page.

Using the `cover_photo`, I can get the photo using by using the following in my HTML:

```
http://graph.facebook.com/{$cover_photo}?type=normal
```

In the last day or so this now seems to require an **Access Token** (& therefore also use **HTTPS**). Now the address is:

```
<img src="https://graph.facebook.com/{$cover_photo}?type=normal&access_token={$access_token}" />
```

However, what was once a bit slow before is now crawling.

**Is there a more effective way of loading up to say 8 cover photo images** at a reasonable size than simply putting the address in there with an Access Token for each one?

This seems inefficient and results in lots of 'blocking' and 'waiting' according to Firebug.

Answer (score 1):

You now have to put `/picture` after the `cover_photo` id. For example,

```
<img src="https://graph.facebook.com/{$cover_photo}/picture?type=normal&access_token={$access_token}" />
```